# How do I deploy a PHP application to Heroku?

Tags: php, .htaccess, heroku, composer-php, foreman

I have a legacy PHP application. The root directory looks like this:

```
.htaccess
index.php
composer.json
composer.lock
Procfile
```

In my procfile I have this:

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 /
```

And in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

And in composer.json this:

```
{
  "require" : {
    "silex/silex": "~1.1",
    "monolog/monolog": "~1.7"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "heroku/heroku-buildpack-php": "*"
  }
}
```

When I deploy to heroku I get no errors, just a blank screen. I am unable to run the app locally with foreman due to it throwing this error:

```
This program requires Apache 2.4.10 or newer with mod_proxy 
and mod_proxy_fcgi enabled; check your 'httpd' command.
```

Additionally, I'm getting a 500 server error on the Heroku site.

I'm wondering if I am doing anything that is obviously wrong here. Not very experienced with deploying PHP applications on Heroku so I'm not sure exactly what the deal is. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Go check the error log …

Comment: Shouldnt this: `web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 /` be something like `web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 .` or `web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 ./`? Looking at the example from the heroku docs they have it set up to point to `web/` making it relative from the `Procfile` location so i would expect yours to do the same. Also I'am confused - is this actually a Silex app or did you just attempt to modify the example app structure they give for PHP deployment?

Comment: First, leave out the trailing slash in the Procfile and see if that helps - that location is relative. Second, if you're getting a 500 still from PHP and there is nothing in `heroku logs` (have you checked that?), then you're setting `error_reporting` to 0 somewhere in your code or you're using `@` to suppress errors from a `mysql_connect` or something similar which crashes, and you should never do that.